# Get a union-like result without using union

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

This is my table structure:

```
Product(ID, Barcode, Name)

ChildProduct(ProductID, Barcode)

ChildProduct(ProductID) REFERENCES Product(ID)
```

Here is some sample data:

```
Product
(1,100,'A')
(2,200,'B')
(3,300,'C')
(4,400,'D')

ChildProduct
(1,101)
(1,102)
(2,201)
(4,401)
```

This is the desired result:

```
(1,100,'A')
(1,101,'A')
(1,102,'A')
(2,200,'B')
(2,201,'B')
(3,300,'C')
```

This can be achieved quite easily with a union:

```
SELECT * FROM Product
WHERE ID IN (1,2,3)
UNION
SELECT * FROM ChildProduct cp
JOIN Product p ON (p.Id = cp.ProductID)
WHERE p.ProductID IN (1,2,3)
```

However, in reality, the `WHERE` part of this query is a complex construct of joins, so I would really like to avoid using `UNION`, so that I don't have to duplicate all that code.

How do I achieve the same results without duplicating my where clause?

Edit: Looks like I simplified it a little bit too much. I tweaked it a bit to show that I have to join ChildProduct and Product in any case.

What I'm really looking for is a way to just loose the union outright.

Comment: Apply the `where` clause on the whole union query. Oracle should be able to push down the restriction in each query individually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do a `UNION` into a derived table, and query that:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT Id, Barcode FROM Product
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ProductId, Barcode FROM PRODUCT) AS ProductAndChild
WHERE ProductAndChild.Id IN (1,2,3)
```

(`UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION`, so it is preferable if you know there aren't going to be duplicates, or if duplicates don't matter)

Comment: I think I may have simplified my use-case a little bit too much. Any way to just loose the union altogether?

Answer (score 2):

Not that I recommend this as a faster option .. however, you can duplicate the results using FULL OUTER JOIN ... O.o

Not sure WHY you'd want to do this ... [edit] didn't notice the purpose of the OP for the simplified where ... tweaked a little - use David's answer .. it addresses your root question :) [/edit]

```
  select * from (
  select nvl(p.id,cp.productid) id,
         nvl(p.barcode, cp.barcode) barcode
    from product p
      full outer join 
           childproduct cp
        on p.id = cp.productid
          and p.barcode = cp.barcode
     )
   where id in (1,2,3)
  /

          ID    BARCODE
  ---------- ----------
           1        101
           1        102
           2        201
           2        200
           1        100
           3        300

  6 rows selected.
```

[edit] tweaked the query to "simplify" the final where .. again, though, this could be done with union as well:
select * from 
( select )
 union
select 
)
where

doesn't change it much ...